# Executar user input em determinado número

Tags: c#

Estou fazendo um programa que calcula uma nota final somando os números e dividindo-os por 4. Gostaria de adicionar a função de digitar quantas notas o usuários quiser.

Este é o código que tenho no momento:

```
        int num0;
        int num1;
        int num2;
        int num3;
        int sum;
        int div;
        String input0 = "";
        String input1 = "";
        String input2 = "";
        String input3 = "";
        Console.WriteLine("Calculador de média escolar\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Por favor, digite o primeiro número:");
        input0 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Por favor, digite o segundo número:");
        input1 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Por favor, digite o terceiro número:");
        input2 = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Por favor, digite o quarto número:");
        input3 = Console.ReadLine();
        num0 = Convert.ToInt32(input0);
        num1 = Convert.ToInt32(input1);
        num2 = Convert.ToInt32(input2);
        num3 = Convert.ToInt32(input3);
        sum = num0 + num1 + num2 + num3;
        div = sum / 4;
        Console.WriteLine("A nota é: " +div);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Agradeceria pela ajuda.

Answer (score -1):

Uma opção é perguntar ao usuário quantas notas ele quer digitar, então, é só fazer um `for` em cima dessa quantidade:

```
int notaTotal = 0;
int qtdeNotas;
int div;

Console.WriteLine("Calculador de média escolar\n");
Console.WriteLine("Por favor, digite quantas notas você tem:");
qtdeNotas = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
for (int i = 1; i <= qtdeNotas; i++){
    Console.WriteLine("Por favor, digite a {0}ª nota:", i);
    notaTotal += Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
div = notaTotal / qtdeNotas;
Console.WriteLine("A nota é: " +div);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!